# How to get list of Attributes for each member of a group from Active Directory such as First Name, Last Name, Email

Tags: c#, active-directory

Here is method. Please take a look at section commented as code here please. I pass group names a string [] parameter and I am looking for attributes for the members of these groups.

```
    public List<Users> GetUsers(string[] groupNames)
    {
        List<Users> employees = new List<Users>();
        string firstName = string.Empty;
        string lastName = string.Empty;
        string mail = string.Empty;

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,     "Name"))
        {
            foreach (var groupName in groupNames)
            {
                foreach (var userPrincipal in   GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, groupName).GetMembers())
                {
                    //code here please
                    employees.Add(new MPI.Domain.Entities.Users { First = firstName, Email = mail, Last = lastName });
                }
            }
        }
        return employees;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetMembers` method that you are invoking will return all members of the group including users and other groups. This is true because in active directory groups can have group members.

To get only users, you have to filter the members. One way to do that is to use the [`OfType` LINQ method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
foreach (var userPrincipal in 
    GroupPrincipal
        .FindByIdentity(context, groupName)
        .GetMembers()
        .OfType<UserPrincipal>())
{
    string mail = userPrincipal.EmailAddress;

    string firstName = userPrincipal.GivenName;

    string lastName = userPrincipal.Surname;

    employees.Add(
        new MPI.Domain.Entities.Users
        {
            First = firstName,
            Email = mail,
            Last = lastName
        });
}
```

This way, you will only go through members that are users. And also the loop variable `userPrincipal` would be of type `UserPrincipal` (instead of the abstract `Principal` class). So you can access the `EmailAddress`, `GivenName`, and the `Surname` properties to access the email, first name, and the last name of the user.

By the way, if you are interested to find the members of the group recursively, i.e., you want to find the members of the groups that are members of the group, there is [an overload to the `GetMembers`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339975(v=vs.110).aspx) method that allows you to do that.